# Making sealed class hierarchy Parcelable

Tags: android-intent, kotlin, parcelable, sealed

I have something similar like the following where I want to pass them around as intent arguments;

```
sealed class BasketType : Parcelable {

    class BasketOne(val basketId: String): BasketType() {

        constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(parcel.readString()) {
        }

        override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            super.writeToParcel(parcel, flags)
            parcel.writeString(basketId)
        }

        override fun describeContents(): Int {
            return 0
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

But I get the following error;

> Abstract member cannot be accessed directly

on the line `super.writeToParcel(parcel, flags)` which is kind of expected.

I've looked around for a workaround but could not find one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply leave out the `super` call. There is no super implementation of that function, which is why it's complaining.

```
override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(basketId)
}
```

the `super` call is only there because the code generation of android studio puts it there without checking that it's actually possible.

Answer (score 74):

if you want `@Parcelize` in `sealed class`, do it like this:

```
sealed class AssistantType : Parcelable{
    @Parcelize data class Dashboard(
        val firstName: String,
        val hasGoal: Boolean,
        val hasOverDuePayment: Boolean
    ) : AssistantType()

    @Parcelize data class Detail(
        val firstName: String,
        val isGoalAchived: Boolean
    ) : AssistantType()
}
```

and Add below code into your App Level gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Adnan, I went nuts trying to add `@Parcelize` to the class itself. That code made the trick.

Comment: Hi. Is that extension in Gradle required or can be ignored? Thanks